# realex showing Mandatory Fields missing: [/request/sha1hash]. error message

Tags: php, realex-payments-api

This is full source code i am using with DCC where I replace merchantid and account with actual values

> $merchantid = "merchantid"; $secret = "secret"; $account = 'account';

This is how i am creating hash

```
$tmp = "$timestamp.$merchantid.$orderid.$amountinCents.$currency.$cardnumber";
$md5hash = md5($tmp);
$tmp = "$md5hash.$secret";
$md5hash = md5($tmp);
```

below is the xml sending code

```
$xml = "<request type='auth' timestamp='$timestamp'>
    <merchantid>$merchantid</merchantid>
    <account>$account</account>
    <orderid>$orderid</orderid>
    <amount currency='$currency'>$amountinCents</amount>
    <DCC_ENABLE>1</DCC_ENABLE>
    <card> 
        <number>$cardnumber</number>
        <expdate>$expdate</expdate>
        <type>$cardtype</type> 
        <chname>$cardname</chname>
        <cvn> 
            <number>$cvvno</number> 
            <presind>1</presind> 
        </cvn>
    </card> 
    <dccinfo>
        <ccp>euroconex</ccp>
        <type>1</type>
        <ratetype>S</ratetype>
        <amount currency='$currency'>$amountinCents</amount>
    </dccinfo>
    <autosettle flag='1'/>
    <md5hash>$md5hash</md5hash>
    <tssinfo>
        <address type=\"billing\">
            <country>ie</country>
        </address>
    </tssinfo>
</request>";

// Send the request array to Realex Payments
$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.realexpayments.com/epage-remote.cgi");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "payandshop.com php version 0.9"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); //This should always be set to 'TRUE' when in production to ensure the SSL is enabled.
$response = curl_exec ($ch);     
curl_close ($ch);
$parseXML = simplexml_load_string($response);
echo "<pre>";print_r($parseXML);die();
```

it return me "320 An internal error has occured." message
i am not sure what i am doing wrong I want to add DCC facility.

Comment: Hi Paritosh,

As I mentioned in my answer, please use SHA1 instead of MD5.

In addition, this "<DCC_ENABLE>1</DCC_ENABLE>" is not valid, please remove that line.

Can I just double check as well that you are processing a DCC Rate Lookup request before submitting this Auth?

https://developer.realexpayments.com/#!/api/dcc/dcc-rate


Seán

Comment: Hi thanks , i have make changes you mention in comment .removed "<DCC_ENABLE>1</DCC_ENABLE>" from xml file and use sha1 `$tmp = "$timestamp.$merchantid.$orderid.$amountinCents.$currency.$cardnumber";
$sha1Hash = sha1($tmp);
$tmp = "$sha1Hash.$secret";
$sha1Hash = sha1($tmp);
`  and passing dcc info as well `<dccinfo>
        <ccp>fexco</ccp>
        <type>1</type>
        <ratetype>S</ratetype>
  <amount currency='$currency'>$amountinCents</amount>
    </dccinfo>` but it still showing me same error message **[result] => 320
    [message] => An internal error has occured.**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. Firstly, I would highly recommend you use the SHA1 algorithm to hash the transaction details instead of MD5.

Secondly, you didn't post your request XML but it must adhere to the following format:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<request type='auth' timestamp='20171025141809'>
<merchantid>Merchant ID</merchantid>
<account>internet</account>
<channel>ECOM</channel>
<orderid>N6qsk4kYRZihmPrTXWYS6g</orderid>
<amount currency='EUR'>1001</amount>
<card>
    <number>4263970000005262</number>
    <expdate>0519</expdate>
    <chname>James Mason</chname>
    <type>VISA</type>
    <cvn>
        <number>123</number>
        <presind>1</presind>
    </cvn>
</card>
<autosettle flag='1'/>
<comments>
    <comment id='1'>Mobile Channel</comment>
    <comment id='2'>Down Payment</comment>
</comments>
<sha1hash>87707637a34ba651b6185718c863abc64b673f20</sha1hash>
</request>
```

Can you please ensure that you have the sha1hash element in the request XML and that it is being populated with the appropriate value.

Best,

Seán

**Realex Payments**

Comment: I have updated question can you please take look at it

Comment: hi, thank for response. my script is working fine now. I just want to confirm one thing previously ( without dcc) i am getting one parameter in response called "batchid" after adding dcc feature i am not getting any reference to it. Can you please provide some details was that removed from response also is it required actually. thank you.

Comment: I'll need more information, like the request you used. For an authorisation you will always receive a batchid. For a DCC Rate Lookup request you won't receive one, as no batch is involved. You just use the obtained rate in the authorisation.